# Android свойство spinner

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

Воообщем у меня есть определенный  spinner щас он выглядит так:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener editViewSpinner = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            // TODO: Auto-generated method stub
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(grayColor);
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(12);
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_cl));
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTypeface(typeFace);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO: Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    spinnerMoney.setOnItemSelectedListener(editViewSpinner);
```

Так же у меня есть функция для смены языка её код здесь приводить не стану, вообщем как мне изменить этот адаптер чтобы я мог потом легко переназначить массив со словами; в часности для меня на другом языке на другом языке.

Answer (score 1):

Для смены языка в андроид приложениях необходимо использовать ресурсы. 
[Оф.документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) и [Сайт Александра Климова](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php)

Создаешь в ресурсах папки с локализацией, en/ru и т.д.
Язык приложения изменяется сам в зависимости от настроек телефона.

Comment: Блин это я все и так знаю я говорю о другом, я использую смену языка "в реальном времени" для этого я заново присваиваю все текста и проблема в том что я хз как их присвоить для спинера через код - программно, вот собственно я и спрашиваю как это сделать??